# Why can't I find wireless-tools in Debian repositories?

Tags: debian, package-management, software-installation, wifi

I have installed the squeeze version of Debian on a computer in offline mode (no internet connection during installation).

After the installation (that was successful) I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` to comment the cd-rom source and uncomment the official Debian repositories. With the computer connected to Internet, the package database seems to update as planned (with `apt-get update`) but I can't find the `wireless-tools` package in the repository: `apt-cache search wireless` does not return anything.

here is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20120929-15:56]/ squeeze main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 _Squeeze_ - Official i386 CD Binary-1 20120929-15:56]/ squeeze main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install.  The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.
#

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Without further information, i.e. `apt-cache policy` we can't help

Comment: Please include your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ... is it possible you only enabled the security updates sources, but not the main ones?

Comment: So these two uncommented lines are not the official general-use repositories, these are the lines I needed to add:
    `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main` and 
    `deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main`
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I could not access the `wireless-tools` package is simply because the main repositories are absent. Add the lines corresponding to your distribution:

`deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main`

`deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main`